# set the size of a UI displayed from a spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code

```
function doGet() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication();
   app.add(app.createHTML("<b>Hello World!</b>"));
   var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   app.setWidth(100);
   spreadsheet.show(app);
  }
```

displays an UI container from a spreadsheet.
How can I set its width to the entire length of the browser window? If I use

```
  app.setWidth("100%");
```

I get an error even if [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_html#setWidth) says that `.setWidth` method accepts percentual values.
Moreover, I want to know if it is possible to anchor its vertical position to the top or the bottom of the browser window, that it to un-center the vertical placement of the UI container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you made a confusion between [the app width](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance#setWidth) and a widget width, the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_uiinstance#setWidth) says 'in pixels'

As for the rest, the answer is no... sorry ;-/

*but you can eventually move the UI app by dragging it by hand, you should add a title to 'grab it by the title'*